# back to initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

As you can see i have an initial view controller with label in it **"Initial ViewController"**. In this view controller i use below code to go to selected tab of **Tab Bar Controller**

```
let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as! UITabBarController
vc1.selectedIndex = selected
let controllers = [vc1]
navigationController!.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
```

In my First View, there's a button **"Present VC"** which presents **"Presented View"**.

```
let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PresentedVC") as! PresentedVC
present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now i want to go back from presented vc to root vc(Initial View Controller). I can do this with:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstNavigationController") as! FirstNavigationController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

but this instantiate Initial View Controller every time and views remain in memory. How can i go back to Initial View Controller without instantiating it?

**PS:** FirstNavigationController is initial Navigation Controller.

[image]

Comment: Use delegation of callback

Comment: and use navigationcontroller.popToRootViewControllrt()

Comment: @SPatel I used even navigationcontroller.popToRootViewControllrt() in my First View and it's not going to InitialVC

Comment: @Hos Ap if you to go previous view controller use popViewControllerAnimated or if you want to go root view controller use popToRootViewController. If you have multiple you have one more option that is add all view controllers to array and use popViewController:animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very beginning you remove the initial view controller by doing this:

```
navigationController!.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
```

All the previous viewControllers are gone now and replaced with the tabbar controller and its children.

If you want to go back to the initial controller, you will have to push the tabbar onto the stack instead of replacing everything with it. E.g.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbarVc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

First when you did this

```
 navigationController!.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
```

the initial VC is deallocated (if it has not a strong references)

to keep it you can use push , pop instead of `setViewControllers` but note it may cause memory issues if you have heavy processing in your app as it will remain in navigationController stack

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the concept between "Presenting" or "Setting" View Controller & "Navigating" the View Controller. You will get the answer, once you understood the concept. Here, it is..

1. When you are setting the ViewController, you are completely replacing the stack container to the new view controller. the way you did it here:

   ```
   navigationController!.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
   ```

   In this case, STACK holds the addresses of the latest set/presented ViewControllers that means previous whole ViewController vanished.
2. On the other hand, if you are navigating to other view controller by pushing it. you can go back to previous controller by simple popping the ViewController address from stack. or to next ViewController by pushing
   e.g:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbarVc, animated: true)

   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   ```

**Summary:**

If you push **TabBarController** then, only you will get **InitialVC**.

Now, in your case, you are setting the ViewController and hence, you are not getting InivtialVC. **Try Pushing tabbarVC** This will work.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbarVc, animated: true)
```